# did my solution produce 0 and 1 with equal probability?

Tags: probability, python, bernoulli-distribution

I am using Python 2.7, tried many times, but never produce result 50 during 100 times test.

```
import random

# fake a Bernoulli distribution with P(1) = 0.3
def Bernoulli():
    if random.random() <= 0.3:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def TossCoin():
    x1 = Bernoulli()
    y1 = x1
    while y1 == x1:
        y1 = Bernoulli()

    return x1 * (1-y1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 100
    result = 0
    while count > 0:
        count -= 1
        result += TossCoin()
    print result
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: This question is pretty unclear, and both initial answerers completely misunderstood what you were trying to do, because you just posted code without any description of what you were trying to do. Your question would have been more immediately answered had you described what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit: I initially completely ignored the `TossCoin()` function for some reason.)

You're doing the following:

- Draw $x_1 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(.3)$. This will be either 0 (70% of the time) or 1 (30% of the time).
- Draw $y_1 \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(.3)$ until $y_1 \ne x_1$. This could more succinctly be represented as: if $x_1$ is 0, set $y_1 := 1$; if $x_1$ is 1, set $y_1 := 0$. Even more succinctly, set $y_1 := 1 - x_1$.
- Return $x_1 * (1 - y_1) = x_1 (1 - (1 - x_1)) = x_1^2$. Since $x_1$ is either 0 or 1, $x_1^2$ is just $x_1$. So you're just returning $x_1$.

Thus, your overall program is just adding up 100 $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(0.3)$ draws, i.e. sampling from $\mathrm{Binomial}(100, .3)$. This doesn't seem to be what you wanted.

---

Your problem is this:

Let $X$ be your first sample from a Bernoulli(.3), and $Y$ the second. Then, as you know, if $X$ and $Y$ are sampled independently:

- $P(X=0, Y=0) = .49$
- $P(X=0, Y=1) = .21$
- $P(X=1, Y=0) = .21$
- $P(X=1, Y=1) = .09$

So, yes, `0 1` and `1 0` are equal probability. If you sampled $X$ and $Y$ independently, [rejecting the sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) when they were both 0 or both 1, then your intention is correct:
$$
P(X=0, Y=1 \mid X \ne Y) = .5 = P(X=1, Y=0 \mid X \ne Y)
.$$

But `TossCoin()` *doesn't take two independent samples*. It takes one sample, and then constrains the other one to be the other value. That's a different thing entirely:
\begin{align}
P(\mathtt{TossCoin}\text{'s samples} = (0, 1))
&= P(X = 0) P(Y = 1 \mid Y \ne X, X = 0)
= .7 \times 1
\\
P(\mathtt{TossCoin}\text{'s samples} = (1, 0))
&= P(X = 1) P(Y = 0 \mid Y \ne X, X = 1)
= .3 \times 1
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Dougal, I tried to generate 0 1 and 1 0 combination in TossCoin, if I generate 1 first, then I tried to get 0, their multiply is 1 (= 1 * (1-0)), and if I get 0 first, then I tried to generate 0, and their multiply is 0*(1-1) = 0, and  I think generate 1/0 and 0/1 are equal probability since (1-p) * p == p * (1-p). But from my testing, it seems not, what is wrong here?

Comment: @LinMa Sorry, I was dumb before and completely misunderstood `TossCoin`. As you say: if you generate 1 first, you return 1. If you generate 0 first, you return 0. So `TossCoin()` just returns the first result of `Bernoulli()` that it calls. `1 0` and `0 1` would be equal probability _if you called them independently_. But that's not what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Dougal, you understand my problem correctly (sorry for not clarity enough the question at the beginning), and want to confirm my understanding is correct, it seems TossCoin function written by me has the same effective of just written one line `return Bernoulli()`?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your `Bernoulli` function returns 1 with probability .3, as the comment notes, not .5. And I don't know what you intended `TossCoin` to do, but what it actually does is return 1 with probability .3, just like `Bernoulli` itself.

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist, I tried to generate 0 1 and 1 0 combination in TossCoin, if I generate 1 first, then I tried to get 0, their multiply is 1 (= 1 * (1-0)), and if I get 0 first, then I tried to generate 0, and their multiply is 0*(1-1) = 0, and  I think generating 1/0 and 0/1 are of equal probability since (1-p) * p == p * (1-p). But from my testing, it seems not, what is wrong here?

Comment: @Glen_b, if you mean this comment, "fake a Bernoulli distribution with P(1) = 0.3", yes, it is written by me.  I tried to generate 0 1 and 1 0 combination in TossCoin, if I generate 1 first, then I tried to get 0, their multiply is 1 (= 1 * (1-0)), and if I get 0 first, then I tried to generate 0, and their multiply is 0*(1-1) = 0, and  I think generate 1/0 and 0/1 are equal probability since (1-p) * p == p * (1-p). But from my testing, it seems not, what is wrong here?

Comment: @LinMa I think the difficulty is your explanation of what you're attempting to do in `TossCoin` is very unclear; and you simply kept repeating the same very unclear explanation. I believe I understand it now. You're trying to use two tosses of an unfair coin (`Bernoulli`) to simulate a fair one (what you're trying to do with `TossCoin`)? You need to make that clearer in your actual question -- you need to provide *context* and a description of your reasoning rather than just code.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Glen_b, yes, I want to form a uniform distribution based on non-uniform distribution. I should make it more clear next time.